# Renewing a wildcard SSL certificate in IIS 6 (1024 to 2048 bit)

Tags: ssl, iis-6

I currently have a wildcard SSL certificate running on IIS 6 and needs to be renewed.  The new certificate bit-strength is now 2048 (the current one that needs to be renewed is 1024).  Is there any easy way to get a certificate request file that is 2048 bit when renewing from a 1024?

I don't see the option to change bit strength for renewing an SSL certificate (I only see this when creating a totally new one from scratch).

Comment: This should be asked on serverfault.com. I dont' have enough rep to move it though.

Comment: At least it gets answered here though. SF grumps would have closed the question.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to do this very same thing, and the way I did it was I had to remove the current certificate completely, then add a new certificate fresh, otherwise, I could not figure out how to update the CSR from 1024 to 2048, which is now a requirement.

So, to answer your question, remove the current certificate first (this might be tricky if it's a busy online store), then go through the wizard and switch the CSR from 1024 to 2048.

Not the best answer, I know, but the only one I could seem to find right off (and the easiest)

Answer (score 2):

Be warned about trying to get clever with this one. I just got myself in a big mess trying to do exactly this same thing without any downtime.

What I did was :

- create another website and generate a cert request for that. made sure to put in the correct common name when generating the request.
- I downloaded the certificate that was generated and installed it in my 'Personal' certificates for the Local Computer account (after [adding certificate snap in](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232137)).
- Did 'replace' on the main website for the certificate and chose the new updated one.

I ended up getting this error (as reported by Chrome) when accessing the https site.

(net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): Unknown error

After playing around and switching back to the original certificate I ended up just removing it and re-keying the certificate. It only led to 1-2 minutes of downtime.

I do think that if you do what I was attempting in the correct order you'd be fine. I think you need to export the .pfx file and then import that. I think whats happening is the original server didnt have the correct private key or something like that and was getting confused.

So I'm upvoting calweb :-)